# java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: You cannot start a load for a destroyed activity

Tags: java, android, android-studio

При запуске приложения на эмуляторе, работает стабильно, но при закрытии диалога и возврата во вкладку "Чат" приложение выбрасывает и выдает ошибку

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.blum, PID: 19900
    java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: You cannot start a load for a destroyed activity
        at com.bumptech.glide.manager.RequestManagerRetriever.assertNotDestroyed(RequestManagerRetriever.java:317)
        at com.bumptech.glide.manager.RequestManagerRetriever.get(RequestManagerRetriever.java:128)
        at com.bumptech.glide.Glide.with(Glide.java:801)
        at com.example.blum.MainActivity$1.onDataChange(MainActivity.java:72)
        at com.google.firebase.database.core.ValueEventRegistration.fireEvent(ValueEventRegistration.java:75)
        at com.google.firebase.database.core.view.DataEvent.fire(DataEvent.java:63)
        at com.google.firebase.database.core.view.EventRaiser$1.run(EventRaiser.java:55)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:938)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7656)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:592)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:947)
```

MainActivity:

```
package com.example.blum;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.TextView;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.annotation.Nullable;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar;
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment;
import androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager;
import androidx.fragment.app.FragmentPagerAdapter;
import androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager;

import com.bumptech.glide.Glide;
import com.example.blum.Fragments.ChatsFragment;
import com.example.blum.Fragments.ProfileFragment;
import com.example.blum.Fragments.UsersFragment;
import com.example.blum.Model.User;
import com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseUser;
import com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseError;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;
import com.google.firebase.database.ValueEventListener;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;

import de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView;

//import com.example.blum.Fragments.ChatsFragment;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    CircleImageView profile_image;
    TextView username;

    FirebaseUser firebaseUser;
    DatabaseReference reference;



    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        getSupportActionBar().setTitle("");

        profile_image = findViewById(R.id.profile_image);
        username = findViewById(R.id.username);

        firebaseUser = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
        reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Users").child(firebaseUser.getUid());

        reference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                User user = dataSnapshot.getValue(User.class);
                username.setText(user.getUsername());
                if (user.getImageURL().equals("default")){
                    profile_image.setImageResource(R.mipmap.ic_launcher);
                } else {
                    Glide.with(MainActivity.this).load(user.getImageURL()).into(profile_image);
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {

            }
        });

        TabLayout tabLayout = findViewById(R.id.tab_layout);
        ViewPager viewPager = findViewById(R.id.view_pager);

        ViewPagerAdapter viewPagerAdapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

        viewPagerAdapter.addFragment(new ChatsFragment(), "Чат");
        viewPagerAdapter.addFragment(new UsersFragment(), "Контакты");
        viewPagerAdapter.addFragment(new ProfileFragment(), "Профиль");

        viewPager.setAdapter(viewPagerAdapter);

        tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);


    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
       switch (item.getItemId()){

           case R.id.logout:
            FirebaseAuth.getInstance().signOut();
            // измените этот код, потому что ваше приложение выйдет из строя
            startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, StartActivity.class).setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP));
            return true;
        }

        return false;
    }

    class ViewPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

        private ArrayList<Fragment> fragments;
        private ArrayList<String> titles;

        ViewPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm){
            super(fm);
            this.fragments = new ArrayList<>();
            this.titles = new ArrayList<>();
        }

        @NonNull
        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {
            return fragments.get(position);
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return fragments.size();
        }

        public void addFragment(Fragment fragment, String title){
            fragments.add(fragment);
            titles.add(title);
        }

        //Ctrl + O

        @Nullable
        @Override
        public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) { return titles.get(position); }
    }

    private void status(String status) {
        reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Users").child(firebaseUser.getUid());

        HashMap<String, Object> hashMap = new HashMap<>();
        hashMap.put("status", status);

        reference.updateChildren(hashMap);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        status("В сети :)");
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        status("Не в сети :(");
    }
}
```

и ChatFragment

```
package com.example.blum.Fragments;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

import com.example.blum.Adapter.UserAdapter;
import com.example.blum.Model.Chat;
import com.example.blum.Model.User;
import com.example.blum.R;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseUser;
import com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseError;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;
import com.google.firebase.database.ValueEventListener;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class ChatsFragment extends Fragment {

    private RecyclerView recyclerView;

    private UserAdapter userAdapter;
    private List<User> mUsers;

    FirebaseUser fuser;
    DatabaseReference reference;

    private List<String> usersList;



    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_chats, container, false);

        recyclerView = view.findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);
        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getContext()));

        fuser = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();

        usersList = new ArrayList<>();

        reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Chats");
        reference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                usersList.clear();

                for (DataSnapshot snapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                    Chat chat = snapshot.getValue(Chat.class);

                    if (chat.getSender().equals(fuser.getUid())) {
                        usersList.add(chat.getReceiver());
                    }
                    if (chat.getReceiver().equals(fuser.getUid())) {
                        usersList.add(chat.getSender());
                    }
                }

                readChats();
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });


        return view;
    }

    private void readChats() {
        mUsers = new ArrayList<>();

        reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Users");

        reference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                mUsers.clear();

                for (DataSnapshot snapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                    User user = snapshot.getValue(User.class);

                    for (String id : usersList) {
                        if (user.getId().equals(id)) {
                            if (mUsers.size() != 0 ) {
                                for (User user1 : new ArrayList< User >(mUsers)) {
                                    if (mUsers.stream().noneMatch(u -> user.getId().equals(u.getId()))) {
                                        mUsers.add(user);
                                    }
                                }
                            } else {
                                mUsers.add(user);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }

                userAdapter = new UserAdapter(getContext(), mUsers, true);
                recyclerView.setAdapter(userAdapter);
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });
    }
}
```

Помогите пожалуйста

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Используйте:

```
Glide.with(getApplicationContext()).load(...)
```

Вместо:

```
Glide.with(MainActivity.this).load(...)
```

Comment: Не помогло, выбрасывает из приложения после перехода во вкладку "Чат"

Answer (score 0):

Помогло добавление

```
if ("default".equals(user.getImageURL()))
```

Спасибо за помощь!